# Detect iframe content height change

Tags: javascript, iframe

There are **plenty** of examples showing how to dynamically set an `iframe`'s height to its content.  This works perfect for me.  The problem I'm now having is that the content can change size without triggering `onload` (think hidden/expandable `div`s).

Is there any way to detect when the size of the `iframe` content has changed?  This is on the same domain and no jQuery, please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would do this by polling regularly (maybe every 200 milliseconds, perhaps more often) using `setInterval`.  You could then compare the size of the content to what it was last time.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe'),
    lastheight;

setInterval(function(){
    if (iframe.document.body.scrollheight != lastheight) {
        // adjust the iframe's size

        lastheight = iframe.document.body.scrollheight;
    }
}, 200);
```

Comment: I had thought about this but then I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Detecting_document_width_and_height_changes: `While you can poll the values of document.scrollWidth and document.scrollHeight to watch for changes to the document size, reading these properties can trigger document reflow, which can make them computationally expensive.`  I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: @Nelson Interesting, didn't know that. I don't know whether it's applicable (it refers to `document.scrollheight` rather than an element's scrollheight, but it is probably something to keep an eye on.  You could always decrease the polling frequency...

Comment: Good point, I'm doing `document.body.scrollHeight`.  The performance hit isn't noticeable in IE on my computer.  I'll try other browsers, but so far this seems like it'll work.

Comment: `scrollheight` is typo. It should be `scrollHeight` instead.

Comment: `iframe.document` returns _undefined_. But with jQuery I was able to get either `$iframe[0].contentDocument.firstElementChild` or `$iframe[0].contentDocument.childNodes[1]`just to get the _html_ object of the iframe, then there's few options such as _offsetHeight_, _clientHeight_ etc

Answer (score 2):

ResizeObserver worked for me:

```
    const iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe')
    
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
        setHeight(iframe.document.body.scrollHeight);
    })
    
    observer.observe(iframe.document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-webkit browsers, there are a few domMutation-Events, that fire when an attribute of an element (e.g. the body element) change. See DOMSubtreeModified and more importantly DOMAttrModified.

The internet explorer does fire the onresize event even on non-windows elements.

Opera honors the domMutation Events.

Webkit on the other discarded these events as a compromise to rendering speed and javascript-performance. Thee is no other way than to check via timeout/interval the effective size of an element.

Comment: I tried `onresize` in IE and it fires as the page is loading, but not after the div expands.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <iframe src="{{ encuesta_lime_sourvey_BASE_URL }}" 
           frameborder="0" 
           style="width: 100%; height: 3100px;"
           id="encuesta"
       
           >
           </iframe>
```

```js
    function setHeight(height) {
        document.getElementById('encuesta').style.height = height + 'px';
    }
    
    let iframe = document.getElementById('encuesta');
    
    iframe.onload = function() {
       const iframeEle = document.getElementById('encuesta');
       const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
             setHeight(iframeEle.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight);
       });
          
       observer.observe(iframeEle.contentDocument.body);
       
    });
```

For my works this, you have to check if the iframe is loaded and is loaded you can manipulate