# React to iframe change of height

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am building a page that contains an iframe

The iframe can change its height during the page life.

I would like to know if it is possible to adapt the height of my iframe to the height of its content.

I tried giving height attribute "auto" or "100%" to the iframe but it doesn't work. Is there another CSS possible solution?

I think I can't use Javascript due to Cross Origin Requests.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513266/detect-iframe-content-height-change

Comment: @Rex thanks for the reference, but I can't use js due to cross origin requests

Comment: There is now way you can somehow get the height of the iFrame if it is cross origin.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is different property for height in iframe.

```
 <style type="text/css">

 iframe {

 max-height: 500px;
 min-height: 300px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: this just says that the height cannot be lower than 300px and bigger that 500px, not that it adapts to its content height

Comment: Just try using max-height:100px;

Comment: it is just an iframe, nothing more